# how to validate values in array and do actions python whatsapp framework

Tags: python, http, github

I am newbie learning python, I need a little help in whatsapp framework in github but that's python programming where my knowledge is limited. here you can see two things:

```
message.text ( here is stored the whatsapp message, so i can create commands)
message.conversation (here you can get the groupid or phone number of the sender)
```

the example code:

```
    # modules/hi_module.py

from app.mac import mac, signals

@signals.message_received.connect
def handle(message):
    if message.text == "hi":
        mac.send_message("Hello", message.conversation)

        # Can also send media
        #mac.send_image("path/to/image.png", message.conversation)
        #mac.send_video("path/to/video.mp4", message.conversation)
```

i want to limit my commands like that "hi" to work only in three groups allowed by me, i am thinking in an array where this is stored. So i am thinking in an idea like that

```
groupIds = { "group": "123456789@whatsapp.net", "group": "123458754@whatsapp.net",}
if "hi" in message.text:
    validategroup()
    #do something
else:
    #print("you are not allowed to do this command")
def validategroup:
    if groupIds in message.conversation:
        validation = true
    else:
        validation = false
```

I am stuck at this part, I don't know how to code correctly the method and how to return and allow command or deny. please help me to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can not do like this

> if groupIds in message.conversation:

As groupIds is dic and you can not find complete dic. you should use the value of the key to find in message.conversation.
One more I want to check is message.conversation get string or list..?
Thanks

Comment: i've created an php json encode to get the data from an database, i am trying to validate the groups in message.conversation in order to allow or deny commands

Comment: did you check with once key value if that is working i.e

Comment: did you check with once key value if that is working i.e

if groupIds['group'] in message.conversation:
Can you please check this.
Once more thing I just notice why you are using same key in dic it will update the previous once.
groupIds = { "group": "123456789@whatsapp.net", "group": "123458754@whatsapp.net",}
{'group': '123458754@whatsapp.net'}

Comment: Hello i've created some similar getting group ID and validating if this is on the list thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Your BOOLEAN values must begin with a Capital Letter ( i.e. True or False ).